# Pivot in sql with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
I have a requirement to show values from multiple tables to a single row . CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1Result](
    [Table1ResultID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedByUserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    )


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2Result](
    [Table2ResultID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Table1Result] [int] NOT NULL,  --primary key of table1
    [Table2Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Table2Overall] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Table2GenterID] [int] NULL,
    [CombinedTable2Outcome] [bit] NULL,
    [Display] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HasOutcome] [bit] NOT NULL,
        )


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table3Result](
    [Table3ResultID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Table3ResultID] [int] NOT NULL, --primary key of table 2 ..here foreigh key
    [Table3Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Table3Value] [int] NULL,
    [Table3StringValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Table3BooleanValue] [bit] NULL,
    [Table3DateTimeValue] [datetime] NULL,
    [Table3DecimalValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Table3Dropdown] [bit] NULL,
    [Table3Validation] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Table3DetailID] [int] NULL,
    [Table3QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CombinedTable3Outcome] [bit] NOT NULL,     
    )
```

Above tables are 3 tables among them . Here 1 st table will have only one row for a particulat table1resultid . There is a foreign key releation ship with the second table ie table2result. There for a table1resultid (from 1st table) there will be multiple records.similarly table2 and table3 are related and so on. My requirement is to display 1 row for a particular id. that is for a particulat table1resultid i need to fetch data from all the tables and display in a single row.I expect the column heading will come as column heading in my result.I googled it and found i can get it through pivot. I could not understand it thouroughly. If someone can help me to figure out it will make my day.

Data in table 1 :

```
1 1-01-2015 5
2 1-08-2016 7
```

Table 2 Sample Data:

```
1   1   Heading FALSE   NULL    NULL    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
2   1   ABC FALSE   5   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
3   1   XXX FALSE   5   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
4   1   KKK FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
5   1   YYY FALSE   NULL    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
6   2   Heading FALSE   NULL    NULL    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
7   2   ABC FALSE   5   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
8   2   XXX FALSE   5   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
9   2   KKK FALSE   NULL    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
```

Table 3 :

```
1   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    TRUE    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   NULL    1   FALSE
2   1   asdasd  NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   NULL    2   FALSE
3   1   sda NULL    22  NULL    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   NULL    4   FALSE
4   1   asdasd  NULL    3   NULL    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   NULL    5   FALSE
5   1   NULL    NULL    4   NULL    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   NULL    9   FALSE
6   1   NULL    NULL    5   NULL    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   NULL    10  FALSE
7   1   sda NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    TRUE    FALSE   NULL    11  FALSE
8   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    TRUE    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   NULL    12  FALSE
9   1   NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   NULL    13  FALSE
10  2   asdasd  NULL    a   NULL    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   5   17  TRUE
11  2   asdasd  NULL    b   NULL    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   5   18  TRUE
        asdasd                                      
13  2   asdasd  NULL    d   NULL    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   5   20  TRUE
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your tags, you cant have mysql and sql server at same time, or 2005 and 2008. Also Include some sample data and desire result that help a lot to understand the problem. And read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joins to accomplish this, however, having a single row or not will depend on your condition (for example table 2 may have 2 entries for table 1 for the same table1id, in this case we need to have some specific criteria)

```
SELECT 
            T1.*
            ,T2.*
            ,T3.*
        FROM
            Table1Result T1
            JOIN Table2Result T2
            ON T1.TABLE1RESULTID = T2.TABLE1RESULT
            JOIN Table3Result T3
            ON T2.TABLE2RESULTID = T3.Table3Result -- this field was marked as table3resultid in the question instead of table3result
        WHERE
            T1.TABLE1RESULTID = 100-- the condition goes here
```

Comment: you are right i can get data from all these tables using joins, here the risk in my requirement is to get the final out put in a row. what i am trying to get is something similar to pivoting the data.I will have multiple records in table 2 for table1resultid

Comment: ok, so if there are multiple rows for a table, then both rows would come side by side (all the columns would repeat again) rather than one after the other? is that what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes...everything in one row for a particular id ..hope you know pivot in excel. i want to achieve the same .

Comment: :I dont want the duplicated colums like iDs .

Comment: as a result of joining tables i may get multiple rows depends on the data.i want to transpose all to a single row. the name column will cme as header.

Comment: I have seen few of your answers with pivot in sql. i think that may help me. i tried but i am not able to come to an answer

Comment: I wonder is it possible to achieve the result what i am expecting using PIVOT?